Error encountered scrapping data using Selenium due to NoneType
I am extracting data from the website https://octopus.energy/dashboard/new/accounts that requires a login. I have been successfully accessing it using Selenium with this code.
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
page = driver.get(electric_meter)
user_name ="xxxx"
pw = "xxxx"

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "username"))).send_keys(user_name)
sleep(0.11)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "password"))).send_keys(pw)
sleep((0.21))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='loginForm']/div[4]/button"))).click()

The issue arises when I attempt to retrieve the information. The below code functions properly; however, it outputs a string containing all the data that could be parsed using regex. Still, I am looking for a more efficient or built-in solution.
print(driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "MeterReadingHistory__content").get_attribute("textContent"))

returns
Nice to be aware of: if you have recently sent in a reading, we have received it - it may just take some time to be displayed. Maybe give it another shot tomorrow. DateReading7th Oct 2024Your reading252046th Oct 2024Your reading251984th Oct 2024Your reading251863rd Oct 2024Your...

I want to put each data point e.g. 6th Oct 2024Your reading25198 into a dataframe.

MeterReadingHistory__content functions properly but I encounter an AttributeError when attempting to retrieve text from MeterReadingHistorystyled__StyledReadingsContainer-sc-1mqak03-0.cEwaaW which states 'NoneType' object does not have 'get_attribute'.
What am I overlooking?

include that line of code... it sounds like it's not found because by class name is going to look for a CSS style class name and the element you are targeting has multiple css style classes associated with it.   (it's got "MeterReadingHistorystyled__StyledReadingsContainer-sc-1mqak03-0" and "cEwaaW"....)  Instead check by attribute of "class"... though it'd be better to use something more unique that CSS class.  Just curious, but are you reading people's utility meters?  (do you also submit readings?)

so you probably want XPATH of something like //div[@class="MeterReadingHistorystyled__StyledReadingsContainer-sc-1mqak03-0 cEwaaW"]

@browermator We do not have a Smartmeter and so can not use the API. So scrap I must. Yes I submit readings everyday like clockwork.

Yes I tried using xpath see edit to my post.

simple syntax issue there.  Use single parentheses before .get_attribute... I think it's trying get_attribute on print, which has no return value.

Spot on. How did I miss that. I will use the xpath solution then. Many thanks

Don't edit the solution into your post. write an answer. After all, if your question already has the answer, why would it need to be a post?

The xpath solution works. I had a syntax error pointed out by browsermator.
This brings all the data.
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='account-management']/div/section/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]").get_attribute("textContent")

This brings the first data point e.g. '7th Oct 2024Your reading25204'
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='account-management']/div/section/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]").get_attribute("textContent")

